# How to create new message in iChat without sending, using Automator to grab selected text

Tags: applescript, ichat, messages

I am trying to create a service that grabs the URL of some link, then create a blank iMessage with that URL in the body. Basically, I want to recreate that Message share feature in Safari in Mountain Lion, but with Reeder.app, specifically. "Copy Link" from the context menu doesn't always work, esp. when sending to a iphone, the URL drops, and all you get is the alias.

I've set up an Automator with Applescript, and I can definitely send a message to a buddy, if those things are specified. I'd prefer to populate that in iMessage, since I won't always be sending to the same person.

Below works, using set input as a proxy for automator's url grabbing at the moment.

```
set input to "http://aol.com"
tell application "Messages"
          set theBuddy to buddy "camelot@mac.com" of service "iCloud"
          send input to theBuddy
end tell
```

Also tried

```
tell application "Messages"
    set theBuddy to buddy "*" of service "iCloud"
    set input to invitation message of text chat of service "iCloud"
end tell
```

Both from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3923965?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Interestingly, in a workaround, using the two buddies will almost always use with 'send input to "buddy@me.com"', i get a working service. it is available in Safari for a URL, but it is not available in Reeder.app as a service for anything. It doesn't show in the context menu, it doesn't show up in Reeder > Services. Odd. Is this a Reeder issue? I noticed that my service is in "Internet" category in Services Manager...I would still rather have a blank iMessage with a URL in the text, so that I can amend if I want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it with UI scripting :

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Messages"
    set input to "http://aol.com" as text
    click button 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    delay 1
    keystroke "Buddy@provider.com" -- type the reciever
    keystroke return -- validate the previous input
    keystroke tab -- move to message input
    keystroke input -- type the message
end tell
```